Shell Script doesn't seem to run using cronjobs in k8
A little new to cronjobs on kubernetes and getting familiar with it.
So I'm trying to migrate my onprem cronjobs to k8 cronjobs. I have created them in the required yaml file with the right mounts. The only issue is, when it comes to executing it, it says cannot open file, not found.
The cronjob spec:
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
    name: stop-lime-job
spec:
    schedule: "0/5 * * * *"
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    jobTemplate:
        spec:
            template:
                spec:
                    containers:
                        - name: stop-lime
                          image: busybox
                          volumeMounts:
                              - name: deployments
                                mountPath: /deployments
                          command:
                              - "/bin/sh"
                              - "-c"
                              - cd deployments/kubernetes_on_premises/
                              - ./lime.sh stop
                              
                    volumes:
                        - name: deployments
                          hostPath:
                              path: /home/limeadm/deployments/
                              type: Directory
                    restartPolicy: Never
---

I've also tried passing it in the  args section as follows:
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args:
   - |
        echo "stop-lime job started"
        cd /lime-deployments/kubernetes_on_premises/
        ./lime.sh stop

But everytime the pod starts up, it gives an error and this is the log:
kubectl logs stop-lime-job-1734095400-9mv6l
stop-lime job started
/bin/sh: ./lime.sh: not found

I even tried to ls to se if the file exists and then did a cat which also prints the contents of the file in the pod. Only issue is it doesn't run the script.

How many nodes are in your cluster? Does the directory you mount as hostpath Is available on all the nodes with equal content? The cronjob Pod can be executed on any of the nodes of the cluster, minus ones with taints. Regarding you doing ls and cat, did you try those from inside a similar running Pod? For example BusyBox doing an infinite sleep loop?

2 nodes in the cluster. And no the hostpath  is only available on the primary node with the script.

Uhm, than I think what is happening is that the Pod is getting scheduled on the other node. You should try adding a node selector and a toleration for control plane no schedule (if you have one) to test if it works when running on the correct node.

If that was the case.. Would it still be possible to use cat and still be able to see the file contents of the script if it was on another node? Curious indeed...

Uhm, how did you test with cat? Did you add it to the command args before running the script? Is the script marked as executable?
